# How to Implement Pagination for Amadeus API's hotels/by-city Endpoint?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, amadeus

I'm working on integrating the Amadeus API into my NestJs application to fetch a list of hotels using the hotels/by-city endpoint. However, it seems that this endpoint does not provide explicit pagination support in the API itself. I'm struggling to figure out the best approach to implement pagination for these results on my application's frontend.

Is there a recommended way to achieve pagination for the hotels/by-city endpoint results? Should I fetch all the results and then implement client-side pagination? Or are there any alternative methods to handle this scenario?